# Деплой простого бота на Heroku

Tags: telegram-bot, heroku

Всем привет ! Залил простого телеграммной бота на хероку по инструкции а он не работает. Логи выдают вот это

На Хероку залился без проблем вроде , после запроса на логи выдало это

```
(.env) MacBook-Air-Akov:pyTelegramBotAPI maureryakov$ heroku logs -t
 ›   Warning: heroku update available from 7.51.0 to 7.59.0.
2021-11-07T12:02:49.596664+00:00 app[api]: Initial release by user maureryakov@aol.com
2021-11-07T12:02:49.596664+00:00 app[api]: Release v1 created by user maureryakov@aol.com
2021-11-07T12:02:49.755456+00:00 app[api]: Enable Logplex by user maureryakov@aol.com
2021-11-07T12:02:49.755456+00:00 app[api]: Release v2 created by user maureryakov@aol.com
2021-11-07T12:10:32.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user maureryakov@aol.com
2021-11-07T12:11:32.555694+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 6c291be7 by user maureryakov@aol.com
2021-11-07T12:11:32.555694+00:00 app[api]: Release v3 created by user maureryakov@aol.com
2021-11-07T12:11:48.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2021-11-07T12:13:08.406523+00:00 app[api]: Scaled to bot@1:Free by user maureryakov@aol.com
2021-11-07T12:13:15.888968+00:00 heroku[bot.1]: Starting process with command `python main.py`
2021-11-07T12:13:16.448025+00:00 heroku[bot.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-11-07T12:13:16.814234+00:00 app[bot.1]: python: can't open file '/app/main.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
2021-11-07T12:13:16.919469+00:00 heroku[bot.1]: Process exited with status 2
2021-11-07T12:13:17.070151+00:00 heroku[bot.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2021-11-07T12:13:17.086865+00:00 heroku[bot.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-11-07T12:13:23.966377+00:00 heroku[bot.1]: Starting process with command `python main.py`
2021-11-07T12:13:25.185970+00:00 heroku[bot.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-11-07T12:13:25.521344+00:00 app[bot.1]: python: can't open file '/app/main.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
2021-11-07T12:13:25.653553+00:00 heroku[bot.1]: Process exited with status 2
2021-11-07T12:13:25.700918+00:00 heroku[bot.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2021-11-07T12:14:15.713469+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=maureryakov.herokuapp.com request_id=dbcde4af-59ed-4634-b05b-1e2d583d5ef6 fwd="176.124.116.61" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Не могу разобраться что к чему .

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: ошибка вполне однозначна и понятна: `can't open file '/app/main.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`. а вот должен ли этот файл там быть, и, если должен, почему его там нет — это уже вам виднее.